# How to display data from JsonRestStore

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo

The following is the code sample I have written. I would like to get the data from REST services and print it on the screen. I could get the response from REST in the JSON format. But, I could not find the way to use store it in the JSONStore and use it. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
dojo.provide("index.IndexService");
dojo.require("dojo.parser"); 
dojo.require("dijit.Editor"); 
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer"); 
dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dojox.data.JsonRestStore");
var xhrArgs = {
        url: "http://localhost:8080/RestApp/service/customers",
        handleAs: "json",
        contentType : "application/json",
        load: function(data){
          alert(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert(error);
        }
      }

dojo.ready(function(){
    // Create a button programmatically:
    var button = new dijit.form.Button({
        label: "View Transactions...",
        onClick: function(){
            // Do something:
            dojo.byId("result1").innerHTML += "Functionality yet to be implemented! ";
        }
    }, "progButtonNode");
    alert('hi');
    var store = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({target: "http://localhost:8080/RestApp/service/customers"});

    alert(store);

    store.get(1).when(function(object){
        alert(object);
        // use the object with the identity of 3
      });



    //var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);

    //compliantStore = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({deferred});


    alert(deferred);
});
```

Returned JSON value is

> {"employees":{"customers":[{"city":null,"accountNo":null,"name":"Name
>   1","id":1},{"city":null,"accountNo":null,"name":"Name
>   2","id":2}],"count":2}}

How would I retrive the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsonRestStore items are actually simple JavaScript objects, therefore you can always directly read properties from items. Like

```
var store = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({target: "http://localhost:8080/RestApp/service/customers"});
myValue = recipeStore.getValue(item,"foo"); //stored in myValue
get = store.getValue;
set = store.setValue;
save = store.save;
// then fetch an item
var myGetValue = get(item,"foo");
var setMyValue = set(item,"foo","bar");
```

In synchronous mode, one can fetch without providing a callback, by directly accessing the results property from the request object that is returned from the fetch operation:

```
var queryResults = store.fetch({query:"?tastes='good'"}).results;
var firstItem = queryResults[0];
```

Did you meant something like that.. Hope it helps

Comment: if i use like get(item,"foo"); where the return value will be stored?

Comment: my returned json value is {"employees":{"customers":[{"city":null,"accountNo":null,"name":"Name 1","id":1},{"city":null,"accountNo":null,"name":"Name 2","id":2}],"count":2}}. How would i retrive each record?

Comment: see the edited code, you will be able to use like: var myGetValue = get(item,"foo");

Comment: it is not working for me. How can I display the JSON resilt to check if I am getting the correct result. Then I can try these methods. Please help me.

Comment: From dojo sources: getValue(item, property, defaultValue) retrieves a property from an item. So, to get value from JsonRestStore you have to pass store.fetch().results[i] as an item, and property you want to get from the item.